# SSIS Package not running after deleting first element

Tags: ssis

This is a simple question and I feel dumb asking but I have researched and dug around for two days and I can't find an answer.

I have a SSIS package that had several Containers, the first of which we not longer need to run.  Apparently there is a way to set the starting point in a package and I can not find it.

Where in the ssis package do you set the starting point for the package if you delete the first element?

The symptom of this package not running is: I ran the build but the package just starts and never moves forward, it doesn't even turn the sequence container header yellow

Comment: I've never needed to specify a starting point.  Did you remember to re-build the package after you deleted the container?

Comment: Yes, I ran the build but the package just starts and never moves forward, it doesn't even turn the sequence container header yellow.

Comment: What does it show in the Progress view/tab when that happens?

Comment: There is nothing to do. SSIS automatically starts on the beggining of the flow. You need to check if the current start point depends on something that made the deleted step.

Comment: The comment is a little more indicative of the problem. In the **View** menu, select *Output*. Keystroke is Ctrl+Alt+O  Now run the package and look for Error in there. If you don't see it, select the entirety of the output and edit it into your question. And then possibly ping me by adding a comment like "@billinkc output is attached"